# spl_autoload and same filenames in different directories

Tags: php, autoload

The problem I am facing is that `spl_autoload($class)` passed in spl_autoload_register callback, will not load classnames which refer to the same filename, but in different directories.

What I want to achieve is using `spl_autoload`, not using `require` and without namespaces, to load automatically following classes:

%Project_Path%/controllers/test.php:

```
class TestController {

}
```

%Project_Path%/models/test.php:

```
class TestModel {

}
```

What I'm doing is replacing the `Controller` or `Model` suffix in the classname with empty string, so it will get the filename `class Test` lowercased is `test`, and adding the spl extension php should go to `test.php`.

In the beginning of the file, I have set the include path to refer either to `pear`, to current directory, to `models` directory and to `controllers` directory.

If there are question, what have I tried - this is what I have tried :) spl_autoload() is not recieving paths, so I have to change the include path in order to include the files.

I succeed in achieving it with require and the explicit path, then the classname, but I was in doubt if it's possible with `spl_autoload` following the current pattern, without changing filename, classname or adding namespace

Answer (score 0):

you can try a function like file :XProject.class.php:

```
class XProject{
    public static function autoload($class) {
        //echo '>> auto load >'.$class.'<br>';

        if (file_exists(BASEPATH . 'core/lib/' . $class . '.class.php')) {
            require_once(BASEPATH . 'core/lib/' . $class . '.class.php');
        } elseif (file_exists(BASEPATH . 'core/utils/' . $class . '.class.php')) {
            require_once(BASEPATH . 'core/utils/' . $class . '.class.php');
        }
    }
}
```

and :

```
include BASEPATH.'core/lib/XProject.class.php';
spl_autoload_register('XProject::autoload');
```

inthis example I supposed %Project_Path% as BASEPATH.
hope this code will help you.

Comment: Your function is using `require` instead of `spl_autoload`

Comment: You did not understand me. Check again my first sentence in the question. In spl_autoload_register I pass in the callback all that is needed to make $class real filename and then pass it to spl_autoload(). No require/include/require_once